# Appium getText() throws NoSuchElementException after sendKeys() on AndroidElement

Tags: android, appium, appium-android

I have EditText with `android:hint="oldtext"`. In Appium testing project find this element by Android UIAutomator:

```
WebElement element = 
  driver.findElementByAndroidUIAutomator("new UiSelector().text(\"oldtext\");
```

then I send new text to the element and invoke get method

```
element.sendKeys("newText");
element.getText();
```

I would like to assert new text but it throws `NoSuchElementException`:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: UiSelector[TEXT=oldText]
For documentation on this error, please visit:     
http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For appium you can use **id**, **resource-id**, **cont-desc** or **xpath** to uniquely identify the element.
If you don't see any id or automationId (cont-desc) in your app element, it is good to ask your developer to put them in the code.

> Using xpath is not recommended but you can use if there is no any id or cont-desc.

[image: pic from http://www.automationtestinghub.com]

Now you can access the your element like following.

```
WebElement element= driver.findElement(By.id("element Id")).sendKeys("new Text");
//or
WebElement element = driver.findElementById("element id").sendKeys("new Text");

//using accessibility id
WebElement element = driver.findElementsByAccessibilityId("accesibility Id");

//using xpath
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//EditText[contains(@text,'oldtext')]"));
```

Comment: you can use **appium desktop inspector** to know the xpath for the element in the screen. Use appium desktop inspector and check your element xpath.

Comment: In my project, there is no id, content-desc etc. so I must search text in EditText only.  As you said "Using xpath is not recommended" and I would like to not using it, but it seems there is no other option.

Comment: Learn how to use **appium desktop inspector** [here](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-desktop-inspector/)

Comment: Learn how to inspect element using appium desktop inspector [here](http://www.automationtestinghub.com/appium-desktop-inspector-inspect-mobile-elements/)

Comment: You should mark this as the accepted answer since you stated it worked.  You might also consider up-voting his answer as is was also "useful"